# Bootstrap 4: How to initialize a modal wrapper plugin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I've built a modal wrapper plugin ([Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com)) that dynamically creates dialogs as needed. I'm able to create multiple instances of the plugin when I initialize it using a unique selector for each trigger button.

I'd like to initialize it once, but have separate instances for each launch button. The issue is that the plugin is ignoring options set via data attributes for all buttons except the first one. No matter which button is clicked, the exact same modal is generated and it's based on options passed on the first button in the queue.

Here a stripped-down snippet of my current setup. Can anyone see what I might be missing?

Here's a sample setup:

**The initialization**

```
$('.open-modal').myModal();
```

**Two sample buttons used to open the modal**

```
// Button 1
<button type="button" class="btn open-modal" data-title="Modal 1" data-target="myModal1" data-remote="test.html">Open modal 1</button>

// Button 2 data attributes are ignored. The Modal always renders with options from button 1
<button type="button" class="btn open-modal" data-title="Modal 2" data-position="right" data-target="myModal2" data-remote="test2.html">Open modal 2</button>
```

**The plugin**

```
... 

const defaults = {      
      type: 'basic',       
      id: 'myModal' + helper.getRandomInt(9999, 1000),      
      title: window.document.title,    
      position: '', //
      remote: null, // content to be loaded via Ajax
      target: 'myModal', // id of the generated modal
      ...  
};

class Modal {
  constructor(el, options) {            
    this._$el = $(el);
    this._el = el;
    this._options = options;
    this._$el.data(PLUGIN_NAME, this);
    this._metadata = this._$el.data();
    this._defaults = this.getDefaults();           
    this._opts = $.extend(true, {}, this._defaults, this._options, this._metadata);            

  }

  // render modal
  render(event) {    
    let cls = this;              
    let $el = this._$el;
    let _bodyID = cls._opts.bodyID;
    let _type = cls._opts.type;    
    let $tpl = $(cls.buildTemplate());        

    $tpl.appendTo("body").modal({
      show: true,
      backdrop: cls._opts.backdrop,
      keyboard: false
    });

    // show content
    if (_type == 'delete') {        
        var $mdlBodyID = $(_bodyID);
        var $warningContainer = $('<p>');
        $warningContainer.text(cls._opts.content).appendTo($mdlBodyID);        
    } else {
        let basicType = _type || 'basic';
        cls.log(`${basicType} modal launched`);
        $.ajax({
          url: cls._opts.remote,
        }).done(cls.onSuccess).fail(cls.onError);
    }                
    // remove modal from DOM when closed
    $tpl.on(cls._opts.hideEvent, {this: cls}, cls.onHidden);
    ...
  }

  ...

}

// pluign definition

$.fn[PLUGIN_NAME] = function (options) {

  var items = this;
  if (items.length) {
      var bm = new Modal(items, options);      
      return items.each(function(e) {   
        let $item = $(this);    
        $item.on('click', function(event) {                
          event.stopPropagation();
          event.preventDefault();
          bm.render(event.type);
        })        
      });
  }
}
```

EDIT 2: A quick reordering of the code snippets for more clarity

Comment: I should also mention that the plugin definition comes right after the Modal class in the same file. I posted them separately for clarity and legibility.

Answer (score 0):

It boiled down to moving the `$.extend` method to the plugin definition, inside the `each` loop.

```
  if (items.length) {
      var bm = new Modal(items, options);      
      return items.each(function(e) {   
        let $item = $(this);    
        // override defaults with options or data attributes
        let settings = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options, $item.data());            
        $item.on('click', function(event) {                
          event.stopPropagation();
          event.preventDefault();
          bm.render(event.type, settings);
        })        
      });
  }
```

Then, it's simply a matter of passing those settings back to the `render` method which now accepts a second paramater just for that purpose.

If it can be of any use to anyone, here are the edits to the render method:

```
 // render modal
  render(event, settings) {    
    let cls = this;              
    let $el = this._$el;
    let _bodyID = cls._opts.bodyID;
    let _type = cls._opts.type;    
    let $tpl = $(cls.buildTemplate(settings));        

    $tpl.appendTo("body").modal({
      show: true,
      backdrop: settings.backdrop,
      keyboard: false
    });

    // show content
    if (_type == 'delete') {        
        var $mdlBodyID = $(_bodyID);
        var $warningContainer = $('<p>');
        $warningContainer.text(settings.content).appendTo($mdlBodyID);        
    } else {
        let basicType = _type || 'basic';
        cls.log(`${basicType} modal launched`);
        $.ajax({
          url: settings.remote,
        }).done(cls.onSuccess).fail(cls.onError);
    }                
    // remove modal from DOM when closed
    $tpl.on(settings.hideEvent, {this: cls}, cls.onHidden);
    ...
  }
```